# Loading codeigniter view with predefined variables

Tags: codeigniter

I do not know if the following is possible. If not other suggestions are appreciated.

In nearly all my controllers I will load some default views. For example header, footer and menu.

I would like to have certain variables auto load for each view.

If I take the header as an example. Into my header I will always load an array of `$css` scripts and an array of `$javascript` files.

> $javascript[] = 'js/jquery.js'; 
>   $javascript[] = 'js/jqueryui.js';

But additionally, depending on the current page logic, I might want to add another javascript file to my `$javascript` variable.

> $javascript[] = 'js/custom.js';

Then ideally, I would like these variables to be automatically inserted as data into the load of the view.

In other words, I just want to call:

> $this->load->view('header');

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create MY_Controller add a public array there then extend from MY_Controller

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller  {
     public $data;

     function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->data['MYVAR'] = 'Something';
     }
}
```

in your other controllers you just do it like this

```
class SomeClass extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct () {
        parent::__construct();
    }

     function index () {
         $this->data['SomeOtherVar'] = 'xxx';
         $this->load->view('viewname', $this->data);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $this->load->vars in your Controller.
I use this in my_controller and all controllers are extend from MY_Controller
For example

```
<?php
    class MY_Controller extends Controller{
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setGlobalViewVariables();
        }

        public function setGlobalViewVariables(){
            $result = array();
            $result['value1'] = 'value1';
            $result['value2'] = 'value1'; 
            $this->load->vars($result);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create an [hook](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) for this, it is very simple